# Checking if a string contains a image

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Would it be possible to detect if a string has an image in it. For example,
'This is an image, talkwalker.com/images/2020/blog-headers/image-analysis.png'.
Then put this image into an

```
<img src={stringsource} />
```

And also keep the previous text that was there.
For example, i tried doing something like

```
const msgstring = 'Hello how are you, check out this image 
https://www.talkwalker.com/images/2020/blog-headers/image-analysis.png'
msgstring.replace(msgstring.slice(msgstring.indexOf('http'), msgstring.indexOf('png')+3),`<img src=${msgstring.slice(msgstring.indexOf('http'), msgstring.indexOf('png')+3)}>`)
```

But this is a static and not very good solution because it only works for images ending in png and they must start in http, or else the source will be invalid.

Comment: How do you define "contains an image?" For example, if the URL is a 404, is that an image? What about base64 images, or raw SVG markup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use regex to replace all the image urls to image tags:

#### Regex

```
/(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\S]*\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp)(?:\?\S+=\S*(?:&\S+=\S*)*)?/gi
```

- `(?:https?|ftp):\/\/` starts with `https://`, `http://` or `ftp://`
- `[\S]*` with anything but not space in between
- `\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp)` ends with `.png`, `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.gif`, `.svg` or `.webp`
- `(?:\?\S+=\S*(?:&\S+=\S*)*)?` query string detector, include the  query string if there are any

#### Substitution

```
<img src="$&" />
```

- `$&` means the matching text. It's the image url in this case.

---

```js
const msgstring = 'Hello how are you, check out this image https://www.talkwalker.com/images/2020/blog-headers/image-analysis.png';

const imageRegex = /(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\S]*\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp)(?:\?\S+=\S*(?:&\S+=\S*)*)?/g;

const result = msgstring.replace(imageRegex, '<img src="$&" />');

console.log(result);
```

#### Edit

As an addition, if you want to replace the non-image url to `<p>` tag, you may use the following regex:

```
((?:(?!(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\S]*\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp)).)+)|((?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\S]*\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp)(?:\?\S+=\S*(?:&\S+=\S*)*)?)
```

Basically it makes two group, one is the normal text, the other is image url.

You may replace them accordingly like this:

```js
const msgstring = 'Hello how are you, check out this image https://www.talkwalker.com/images/2020/blog-headers/image-analysis.png Hello how are you, check out this image https://www.talkwalker.com/images/2020/blog-headers/image-analysis.png?alt=media Hello how are you, check out this image https://www.talkwalker.com/images/2020/blog-headers/image-analysis.png?alt=media&test=aaa&a=b Bye';

const imageRegex = /((?:(?!(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\S]*\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp)).)+)|((?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\S]*\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp)(?:\?\S+=\S*(?:&\S+=\S*)*)?)/g;

const result = msgstring.replace(imageRegex, (_, text, img) => text ? `<p>${text.trim()}</p>` : `<img src="${img}" />`);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. Would it also be possible to return a bool result if a string contains an image?

Comment: One more thing, would it also be possible to replace the text inside a <p> element? In essence, the final result would be <p>Hello how are you, check out this image</p> <img src='https://www.talkwalker.com/images/2020/blog-headers/image-analysis.png'>

Comment: @JoshuaBitton I've updated the answer, see if it works

Comment: Works perfectly as I needed it to! thanks so much

Comment: How can i edit the regex to also include, '?alt=media', meaning if it ends in '?alt=media' (no quotation)

Comment: Try [`((?:(?!(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\S]*\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp)).)+)|((?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\S]*\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp)(?:\?\S+=\S*(?:&\S+=\S*)*)?)`](https://regex101.com/r/ZEThOZ/1/)

Comment: Thanks so much, I don't even know how much you have helped me!

Comment: One last thing, would this also work with youtube videos, if i change the regex to : var youtubeReg  = /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?/;

Answer (score 1):

Try this bro..

```
const msgstring = 'Hello how are you, check out this image 
   https://www.talkwalker.com/images/2020/blog-headers/image-analysis.png'
   var test = (/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(msgstring)
```